# Generate strings based on the array from backend - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate this kind of structure based on the data which I am getting from server. The array looks like this

```
this.topics = [{
  "name": "beauty",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "career",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "childcare",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "crafts",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "culture",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "fashion",
  "selected": true
}, {
  "name": "finances",
  "selected": true
}, {
  "name": "fitness",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "food",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "health",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "home",
  "selected": true
}, {
  "name": "personal",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "relationships",
  "selected": false
}, {
  "name": "religion",
  "selected": false
}]
```

So I want to send request with those topics which are selected in this format.

```
{{ base_url  }}/listings?num_items=1&start=3&topics[]=food&topics[]=home
```

This is what i want to add &topics[]=food&topics[]=home, so from this.topics I need to take selected: true and take name and add in that topics[]

Comment: Alright. What've you tried?

Comment: Can you please add the data with the question? Do you want to parse the backend data and get this array of objects? Please elaborate!

Comment: I didn't try yet anything, honestly I don't know what to do and I need help. You have data here which is this.topics, I just want to get from array objects which have selected: true and make a string for request

Comment: But `food` isnt selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the topics to their name and add the `topics[]=` in front and join them by `&` and add that to the url:

```
   const topics = this.topics
      .filter(topic => topic.selected)
      .map(topic => "topics[]=" + topic.name)
      .join("&");
   const url = "/listings?num_items=1&start=3&" + topics;
```

Comment: Nice readable solution. But it needs a filter on `selected` before mapping.

Comment: @kim yeah then just `.filter()` before...

Answer (score 2):

You may filter the topics based on the `selected` key first using `Array#filter` and then apply `Array#reduce` on the filtered array to generate the URL string:

```js
let topics = [{"name":"beauty","selected":false},{"name":"career","selected":false},{"name":"childcare","selected":false},{"name":"crafts","selected":false},{"name":"culture","selected":false},{"name":"fashion","selected":true},{"name":"finances","selected":true},{"name":"fitness","selected":false},{"name":"food","selected":false},{"name":"health","selected":false},{"name":"home","selected":true},{"name":"personal","selected":false},{"name":"relationships","selected":false},{"name":"religion","selected":false}];

let result = '{{ base_url  }}/listings?num_items=1&start=3';
result = topics.filter(item => item.selected)
  .reduce((string, { name }) => `${string}&topics[]=${name}`, result);

console.log(result);
```